# Running a docker image gives - Unable to find image error

Tags: python, docker, flask

On a Ubuntu machine, I have built a docker image of a Python flask project and saved it locally on a folder.

**/docker-images/my_flask_project.tar**

When I run this using this command -

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8000:8000 my_flask_project
```

the error message is -

> Unable to find image 'my_flask_project:latest' locally

1. What is wrong here ?
2. What is the proper way to build docker image, save it locally and run it ?
3. I want to give this docker image to a friend via a USB drive, that's why need the local copy.

This is the output for `sudo docker images` -

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my_flask_project    latest              a81f138bbf93        17 hours ago        1.31GB
<none>              <none>              d43c7afba099        17 hours ago        1.19GB
```

Comment: How did you actually create the `.tar` image?

Comment: I used this command to copy the docker image to a local folder - sudo docker save <docker_img_id_of_ur_file> -o ./<new_filename>

Comment: Then you should have the image locally already. If not, you can use [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/).

Comment: update the question with output of command - sudo docker images

Comment: The image *is* available locally.

Comment: Why don't you use a repository in Docker-hub ? You can make it private and give rights only  to your friend.

Comment: @dejdej .. Okay. I didn't knew that. Thanks. Will do that

Comment: @KlausD. let me try locally to install. the image is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share it via a USB in a tar file format, you can use the `docker save` option and then ask your friend to use the `docker load` option.

#### Commands at your end

`$ docker save -o filename.tar image_name:tag && gzip filename.tar`
This will give a tar.gz file which will be less in size than the tar file as we are compressing it.

Transfer the tar.gz file to the USB drive. Once your friend has transferred the tar.gz file on their system, execute the below command.

#### Commands at your friend's end

`$ docker load < filename.tar.gz`

This will load the docker image locally into docker's local image store.

Answer (score 1):

One approach concerning image sharing is using [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) private repository:

Set up private repository:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/

Login to dockerhub: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Push desired image:
`docker push NAME[:TAG]`